# Chrome: format specifier prints NaN instead of number

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, console.log

Referring the chrome dev-tools [documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/console-write), I wrote a simple snippet in the chrome debugger console which is like so -

```
var age = prompt("How old are you?");
console.log(age); //10
console.log('You are %d years old', age); //You are NaN years old
```

It appears strange that on the last line `NaN` is printed instead of 10. Anything obvious that I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`prompt` always returns a string¹; `%d` expects a number and doesn't, apparently, coerce. Convert the age to a number first, e.g.

```
var age = +prompt(/*...*/);
// or
var age = parseInt(prompt(/*...*/, 10));
// or any of the other ways to convert strings to numbers
```

---

¹ *(or `null` if the user cancels, on some browsers, including Chrome)*

Comment: You could also use `%s` instead of `%d` without conversion.

Comment: @AlexisWilke: Indeed one could. :-)